# Error en validar formulario dinámico select option - PHP

Tags: php, formularios

El problema en la validación se encuentra en el formulario dinámico `Select -> Option` donde el `Select -> option` tiene por defecto (Selecciona un producto) con el `value="0"` siendo un value `0` al no seleccionar un producto el servidor mostrará un mensaje de error ***"Por favor debe seleccionar un producto"***

El `Select -> option` es generado automaticamente con **PHP** tomando en cuenta los valores del `array` donde el primer bloque tiene un `value="0"` mientras el segundo bloque tiene un `value="1"` y así sucesivamente.

**Ejemplo**

```
<select name="producto">
  <option value='0'>Selecciona un producto</option>
  <option value='1'>Producto1</option>
  <option value='2'>Producto2</option>
</select>
```

> En el siguiente código no presenta ningún problema ya que los campos de `option value""` es numerado `<option value='".$i."'>`

```
   <?php
     $datos = array("Selecciona un producto","Producto1","Producto2");
     for($i=0; $i<count($datos); $i++) {
        if($i==$seleccionado) {
           echo "<option value='".$i."'>".$datos[$i]."</option>";
        }else {
           echo "<option value='".$i."'>".$datos[$i]."</option>";
        }
     }
  ?>
```

> El único problema fue al recibir los datos del formulario al correo donde los campos seleccionado llegaban con el valor del `Select option` es decir en vez de llegar `Producto1` llegaba el valor del `value="1"` es decir llegaba al correo el número 1 en vez del nombre del producto es entendible debido a que el valor del `value=""` son enumerados numéricamente.

Para solucionar el problema al recibir los datos al correo realice el siguiente cambio:

```
echo "<option value='".$datos[$i]."' selected>".$datos[$i]."</option>";
```

Ahora sí perfectamente recibía el nombre del producto seleccionado en vez del número.

**AHORA EL PROBLEMA**

> El problema que se presentó haber realizado aquel cambio es que ya el `value=""` ya no es numérico y la validación **PHP** se pierde generando un `Select -> option` de esta manera:

```
<select name="producto">
  <option value='Selecciona un producto'>Selecciona un producto</option>
  <option value='Producto1'>Producto1</option>
  <option value='Producto2'>Producto2</option>
</select>
```

**contacto.php**

```
      <div id="producto">
        <select name="producto">
        <?php
          $datos = array("Seleccione un producto...","Producto1","Producto2","Producto3","Producto4","Producto5");
          for($i=0; $i<count($datos); $i++) {
            if($i==$seleccionado) {
              echo "<option value='".$datos[$i]."' selected>".$datos[$i]."</option>";
            }else {
              echo "<option value='".$datos[$i]."'>".$datos[$i]."</option>";
            }
          }
        ?>
        </select>
        <div class="seconds"><?php if (!empty($errorsAsun)) { echo "$errorsAsun"; } ?></div>
      </div>
```

(Validación del formulario) **form.php**

```
session_start();
$seleccionado = NULL;

if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST['producto'][0])) {
    $errorsAsun = "\n Debe seleccionar un producto";
  } else {
    $seleccionado = dataForm($_POST['producto']);
  }
}

function dataForm($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
```

**MI PREGUNTA**
¿Cómo soluciono el problema de la validación del `Select -> option`?

Comment: uh... pero en qué parte está la validación del select o de cualquier otro campo?

Comment: @amenadiel Mmm.. no se supone que se toma el valor `name="producto"` para validar con `PHP` o estoy mal o lo estoy realizando mal el único problema que tengo es el `select option`

Comment: No te marca error porque realmente el "Seleccione un producto..." sí tiene un valor. Mira mi respuesta.

Comment: @Josues no he dicho nada. Pensé que tenías validación en el frontend, lo entendí al revés

Comment: @amenadiel La validación lo estoy realizando directamente con **PHP**

Answer (score 1):

No le pongas valor al de "Seleccione un producto...", es más, ponlo fuera.

```
<div id="producto">
        <select name="producto">
           <option value="">Seleccione un producto...</option>
        <?php
          $datos = array("Producto1","Producto2","Producto3","Producto4","Producto5");
          for($i=0; $i<count($datos); $i++) {
            if($i==$seleccionado) {
              echo "<option value='".$datos[$i]."' selected>".$datos[$i]."</option>";
            }else {
              echo "<option value='".$datos[$i]."'>".$datos[$i]."</option>";
            }
          }
        ?>
        </select>
        <div class="seconds"><?php if (!empty($errorsAsun)) { echo "$errorsAsun"; } ?></div>
      </div>
```

También te recomiendo que hagas la validaciones mendiante javascript o mínimo ponle el atributo required al select para que no hagas la petición al servidor nada más por eso (igual no le quites la validación del servidor).

```
<select name="producto" required>
```

Comment: Creo que no fui demasiado claro en mi pregunta la he editado nuevamente, por otra parte amigo el ejemplo que has indicado no soluciona el problema debido que el problema es otro directamente en la validación **PHP** o en el formulario dinamico.

Comment: Compañero, tu problema te repito es que "Seleccione un producto..." tiene valor. Por eso tu validación php no funciona, PORQUE NUNCA VA A IR VACÍO. Quita a "Seleccione un producto" desde el array y ponlo físicamente como un option sin value.

Comment: Amigo he probado el ejemplo pero no funciona, el problema lo he detallado en mi actualización de mi pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Para generar la estructura que incluyes en tu pregunta, hazlo de esta manera:

```
<?php
    <div id="producto">
        <select name="producto">
        <?php
          $datos = array("Seleccione un producto...","Producto1","Producto2","Producto3","Producto4","Producto5");
          for($i=0; $i<count($datos); $i++) {
              if($i==$seleccionado) {
                  echo "<option value='".$i."' selected>".$datos[$i]."</option>";
              }else {
                  echo "<option value='".$i."'>".$datos[$i]." </option>";
              }
          }
        ?>
        </select>
        <div class="seconds"><?php if (!empty($errorsAsun)) { echo "$errorsAsun"; } ?></div>
     </div>
?>
```

De esta manera, estarás usando el índice del array en lugar de su valor, generando los valores 0, 1, 2, etc... para cada una de las opciones del `select`

Además, la comparación `if($i==$seleccionado)`  funcionará de esta manera.

Comment: Hola, aquel ejemplo lo he utilizado como especifiqué en mi pregunta? Pero al utilizar aquel ejemplo al momento de enviar el formulario y revisar el correo me llega a mi cuenta de correo el valor del value en vez del nombre del producto seleccionado.

Comment: Puedes mapear el valor en un array y transformarlo en un valor de texto descriptivo, es lo usual. O bien, mantener el ejemplo original y sustituir el if por `if($datos[$i}==$seleccionado) {`

Comment: Hola @Muriano me podrías explicar y crear un ejemplo de lo que me mencionas en el comentario ***(Puedes mapear el valor en un array y transformarlo en un valor de texto descriptivo)*** suena muy interesante pero realmente para mi es algo nuevo aquella opción que me indicas a pesar de que me has dicho un ejemplo más sencillo en el comentario me gustaría optar más por la primera opción más que todo sería algo nuevo por entender y sobre todo aprender puedes explicarme con un ejemplo a mi problema. GRACIAS :)